# Updating Twitter Status: Character Escaping and URLs

Tags: php, api, twitter

I pass text from a POST variable from a form on my site to Twitter and I save this message on my own site. When I view the entry on my site it is absoultly fine. However, in some cases when there is an apostrophe in the message twitter updates the status of a user but escapes the apostrophes and this can be seen on the users status!

This doesn't happen when I update my twitter status on the twitter site. So I am wondering is there a way I need to pass text to twitter?

I currently do this and I make use of this awesome Twitter class. http://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/tree

```
$success = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $_POST['message'].$URL.$key));
```

In addition, passing URLs to twitter use to automatically link the URL but now this just appears as text?

Has twitter made changes in the past month that would cause the above to happen? If not how can I overcome this?

Thanks all

### EDIT

More Code:

```
function tweetit(){
    global $URL;
    global $key;

    include './twitter/EpiCurl.php';
    include './twitter/EpiOAuth.php';
    include './twitter/EpiTwitter.php';

    $consumer_key = 'hidden';
    $consumer_secret = 'hidden';

    $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

    $twitterObj->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

    $success = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' =>  $_POST['message'].' '.$URL.$key));

    return $success->response['id']; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your php config has `magic_quotes_gpc` turned on, which automagically calls addslashes on all input (e.g., your POST values).  I'd read up on addslashes/stripslashes in the php manual.

Comment: You sir are a genius. I used stripslashes on what I passed to twitter and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version?  Not sure what the problem is since one of the unit tests for the library puts in single quotes (among other random characters).

http://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/blob/master/tests/EpiTwitterTest.php#L90

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jaisen. I was not using the latest from Git - but I am now and did another test and I seem to get the same thing. I am sure there is nothing wrong with your code as it is probably working for your guys fine when you use single quotes. I am sure its not twitter, so whats left is me and my code! I have edited my question with how I use your classes. Maybe there is something wrong there? If not, what else could I try?

Comment: Repped you for actually writing the classes - not enough of a thanks but a good gesture at the very least! :)

Comment: Heh, gracias. (need 15 chars)

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlentities function for this.

```
$success = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => htmlentities($_POST['message']).$URL.$key));
```

Or htmlspecialchars:

```
$success = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']).$URL.$key));
```

Comment: Just tried the htmlspecialchars - but it didn't work as all characters such as doubles quotes ans single quotes are still being escaped!

Comment: Just tried that, it actually added twice as many back slashes as before! :(

Comment: Ok, then with urlencode function? because if class uses url parameters  to send can be this! :)

Comment: This didn't work either as I got: "Funny+time%5C%27s+lol" when I typed in "Funny time's lol" - this is very strange. I can't figure out if the problem is how I am passing my string or the string itself??

Answer (score 0):

After you receive the post but before you send it off via the curl, remove slashes with `stripslashes`

```
urlencode(stripslashes($posted_status_update));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Twitter behaves differently if called with www.twitter.com instead of twitter.com. This is a known bug.

http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=890&can=1&q=www&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Opened%20Modified%20Component